# How to map function efficiently in Jax over multiple arguments (tuple/lists) that each have inconsistent shapes

Tags: python, jax

Say one would like to compute the following effficiently

```
from jax import numpy as jnp

xs = [jnp.zeros((1, 3)), jnp.zeros((3, 2, 3))] # iterable with different shape elements
ys = [jnp.ones((1, 3)), jnp.ones((3, 2, 3))] # iterable with different shape elements

def f(x, y):
    return jnp.sum(x - y)
```

How should i be able to efficiently calculate:

```
res = []
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    res.append(f(x, y))
```

without a for loop?

I have tried `jax.vmap` but it is not able to handle the inconsistency shape change in `xs`, `ys`.
I was expecting some way of performing the above task efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

None of JAX's loop-like constructs (`vmap`, `lax.map`, `lax.scan`, etc.) is built for iterating over values of different shapes. The one thing you could use is `tree_map`:

```py
from jax.tree_util import tree_map
out = tree_map(f, xs, ys)
```

but computationally, this will basically be equivalent to a Python list comprehension:

```
out = [f(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]
```

One of those solutions is probably your best bet, unless you can restructure the problem somehow such that your loops/maps are over statically-sized arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a map function is very efficient in cases like this. Try using *jax.lax.map*

```py
from jax import lax
from jax import numpy as jnp

xs = [jnp.zeros((1, 3)), jnp.zeros((3, 2, 3))] # iterable with different shape elements
ys = [jnp.ones((1, 3)), jnp.ones((3, 2, 3))] # iterable with different shape elements

def f(x, y):
    return jnp.sum(x - y)

res = lax.map(f, xs, ys)
```

Comment: am i missing sth cause [`lax.map`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.map.html) essentially only takes one argument other than `f` itself, putting `xs, ys` into a `(xs, ys)` seems also not work there.

Comment: Indeed `lax.map` only works for functions of a single argument, and that argument must be an array, not a list. I don't think it can be used in this case.

Comment: my bad. I misread the problem. Shame on me :(